# Delete a line that contain an occurence in the first or second column

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to del a line that contain the occurence in the first or second column (separator `\t`). For exemple :

```
line 1  uni:1 uni:2 blabla blabla

line 2  uni:3 EBI:1 blbla blabla
```

I Want to delete the line2. The "blabla" text can contain the occurence (EBI) but I don't want to select by the rest of the text, just with the two first column.

I try : `awk -F "\t" '{print $1 $2}' file1 |grep -v EBI > file2`
but this will stock just the first and second column and not the entire line.

I try this too : `awk -F "\t" '{print $1 $2}'file1 |grep -n EBI`
and `sed "numberOfLined" file1 >file2`

But I have a lot of occurences so I don't want to write all numbers of lines by hand.

Comment: I am not able to understand this.  Can you add some more line, and also some example output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if` statement and regex matching via `~`:

```
awk -F '\t' '{if (! (($1 ~ ".*EBI.*") || ($2 ~ ".*EBI.*"))) {print $0} }'
```

And thanks to comments, it could looks even better:

```
awk '!($1~/EBI/ || $2~/EBI/)'
```

Comment: That can be reduced to just `awk -F '\t' '! (($1 ~ ".*EBI.*") || ($2 ~ ".*EBI.*"))'` You don't need to write all the supporting code that awk does for you by default.

Comment: I must say this was one of the most complex I have see to write just this: `awk '$1!~/EBI/ && $2!~/EBI/'` or `awk '!($1~/EBI/ || $2~/EBI/)'` `-F\t` is not needed, since tab is default for `FS`